# How to properly handle multi words synonym expansion using elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have the following synonym expansion :

```
suco => suco, refresco, bebida de soja
```

What i want is to tokenize the search this way:

Search for "suco de laranja" would be tokenized to ["suco", "laranja", "refresco", "bebida de soja"].

But i'm getting it tokenized to ["suco", "laranja", "refresco", "bebida", "soja"].

Consider that the "**de**" word is a stop word. And i want it to be ignored on the query like "bebida de laranja" becomes ["bebida", "laranja"]. But i don't want it to be considered on the synonym tokenization so "bebida de soja" still stays as one token "bebida de soja".

my settings :

```
{
    "settings":{
        "analysis":{
            "filter":{
                "synonym_br":{
                    "type":"synonym",
                    "synonyms":[
                        "suco => suco, refresco, bebida de soja"
                    ]
                },
                "brazilian_stop":{
                    "type":"stop",
                    "stopwords":"_brazilian_"
                }
            },
            "analyzer":{
                "synonyms":{
                    "filter":[
                        "synonym_br",
                        "lowercase",
                        "brazilian_stop",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ],
                    "type":"custom",
                    "tokenizer":"standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to make following two changes. First one directly relates to the question you asked and the second one is a suggestion.

1. Instead of using expansion of multiple synonyms, do the opposite i.e. all the synonyms points to a single word synonym. So, change `"suco => suco, refresco, bebida de soja"` to `"suco, refresco, bebida de soja => suco"`
2. Change the order of filters in `synonyms` analyzer. Place `lowercase` before `synonym_br`. This will ensure that case does't effect `synonym_br` token filter.

So final settings will be:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "synonym_br": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "suco, refresco, bebida de soja => suco"
          ]
        },
        "brazilian_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_brazilian_"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "synonyms": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "synonym_br",
            "brazilian_stop",
            "asciifolding"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### How does this work?

For input `bebida de soja` filter apply in the following order:

```
Input Filter        Result tokens
====================================
lowercase           bebida, de, soja
synonym_br          suco             <------- all the above tokens(including position) exactly matches a synonym
brazilian_stop      suco
asciifolding        suco
```

Let's see `brazilian_stop` in action. For this we need an input which doesn't match the synonym but have `de` in it. E.g. `de soja`:

```
Input Filter        Result tokens
=================================
lowercase           de, soja
synonym_br          de, soja  <------- none of the tokens (independently or combined(including position)) matches any synonym
brazilian_stop      soja      <------- de is removed as it is a stopword
asciifolding        soja
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, thanks. But the case is that the name of the product is "refresco" but the generic name of the product is suco. So what i want is, when people search for "suco" they get the products that contain the word "suco" and also the "refresco" ones. If i change my expansion synonym to a contraction like you recommend, it would have the opposite effect. People would search for "refresco" and get the "suco" products, but searching for "suco" would match only the "suco" ones. Am i right ?

Comment: `refresco` or  `suco` both will get tokenize to `suco` at index time. So lets say doc 1 has a field `product` (analyzer : synonyms) with value `refresco`. It will get tokenised and indexed as `suco`, doc 2 lets say has `suco` as `product` value, will be indexed as `suco`. If a user search for `refresco` the search query while matching against `product` field will by default use the same analyser on search string; i.e. for `refresco` elastic will apply `synonyms` analyzer which will result in token `suco`. So actually it will match for docs having `suco`. Therefore both will match as expected.

Comment: @EduardoJunior Does the above make sense? Is you problem resolved? Feel free to get more clarification if required.