# Enable autocomplete querying in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to build an ElasticSearch index which will have documents with product names, for instance of laptops -

```
{ "name" : "Laptop Blue I7"}
```

Then I want to use it for autocomplete suggestion by querying the ES index. I have 2 main constraints:

1. There can be Synonyms of the name -

I want to define Synonyms for terms, like "Notebook" for "Laptop"
The ingested documents can be of the following kind -

```
"Laptop Blue I7"
"Laptop Blue I7"
"Laptop Blue I7"
"Laptop Blue I7"
"Laptop Red I7"
"Laptop Red I7"
"Notebook Blue I7"
```

Now, I am adding the following settings and mapping file while creating the index -

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "synonyms" : ["Laptop,Notebook"]
                    }
                },
        "analyzer": {
        "synonym" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "keyword",
                        "filter" : ["synonym"]
                    }
}}}}, 
"mappings": {
    "catalog": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "synonym"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Querying -

When I query the data, with "Notebook", 
the preferred response should be ordered in terms of frequency and synonym. However, when I query, the response is normally independent of the synonym and frequency. I use the following query -

```
/_search
{"query": {
        "query_string" : {"default_field" : "name", "query" : "Notebook"}
            } }
```

The response I get is -

```
"Notebook Blue I7"
```

While I would hope the response to be either of the following -

```
"Laptop Blue I7"
"Laptop Red I7"
```

or

```
"Notebook Blue I7"
"Laptop Blue I7"
"Laptop Red I7"
```

Any insights in resolving this would be helpful. Thanks

========
Edit 1:

When I use `\_analyze` on "Notebook" the response is

```
{'tokens': [{'end_offset': 3,
             'position': 0,
             'start_offset': 0,
             'token': 'Notebook',
             'type': '<ALPHANUM>'},
            {'end_offset': 3,
             'position': 0,
             'start_offset': 0,
             'token': 'Laptop',
             'type': 'SYNONYM'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with your `keyword` tokenizer which you have used in your `synonym` analyzer. Please do below things to debug your issue.

1. Check the tokens generated for your matched and unmatched documents using [analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/indices-analyze.html) API.
2. Use [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) API, to understand how its generated tokens and how its matching against your inverted index.

If tokens generated for your documents in Inverted index match with the tokens generated from your search term, then elasticsearch will show it matched and explain query gives a lot of other information like how many documents in a shard matched the search term and its score etc.

Above is just a very basic steps to troubleshoot your issue, but you have not implemented a proper autocomplete search which in turn should return results for `note` and `lapt` in your case. To implement this you need to use `edge n gram` analyzer and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html) ES official post can help you implement this.

Let me know if you face any other issue or requires any clarification.

---

Comment: The reason I chose `keyword` over `standard` was that for multi-word synonyms like `"USB3 Cable, Type C"`, it would split at `whitespaces` and cause miss-match. I had hoped `keyword` would preserve the spacing. Is there any other way to deal with multi-word synonyms?

Comment: @User54211 multi-word synonym requires special handling and https://medium.com/@purbon/handling-similar-words-in-elasticsearch-9c80aba88627 is an interesting read for this.

Comment: @User54211 , meanwhile let me know if you understand why single word synonym didn't work for you?

Comment: I think I did, I will go through the `edge n gram` link you shared and try implementing based on that. 
Once I change the mapping to `standard`, I am curious if there is a way to get the current code to work for the full query of "Notebook"

Comment: @User54211, can you provide the tokens generated for your documents using the `_analyze` api link which I shared earlier in my answer?? this will help to identify if we can do something??

Comment: I have added the response as `[Edit1]` to the post. It seemed to be the `mapping` or `query` could be causing the non-response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194007/discussion-between-amit-khandelwal-and-user54211).

Answer (score 1):

As Amit mentioned, to implement autocomplete `edge n gram` is what you should consider. I would like to explain why the setting you used didn't work for the complete word `Notebook` which when queried didn't yield the expected result. For this lets understand how analyzer above will work.

The `synonym` analyzer defined in the settings has two components, `tokenizer` and token `filter`. For an input string first the tokenizer will be applied. The ouput of the tokenizer will be token(s). These will then act as input of token `filter` and will result in final set of token(s).

You can read more on how analyzer works [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html).

#### Now lets consider the first e.g. ***`Laptop Blue I7`***

For this input string first the `keyword` tokenizer will be applied and as you might be knowing that the keyword tokenizer takes input string and generate a single token which is the same input string without any modification. So the output of tokenizer will be `Laptop Blue I7` as a single token. Now this token  will act as input for `synonym` token filter. According to the definition, `Laptop` and `Notebook` are synonyms but none of them matches the token `Laptop Blue I7` so ultimately this filter will be doing nothing and will pass on the token as it is. So the final token generated will be `Laptop Blue I7`.

So when you search for `Notebook` it will not match the document with `name` value as above.

Note that if the input string is just `Laptop` or `Notebook` you will get the expected tokens because the keyword tokenizer will be generating single word token for the input. This is why _analyze on "Notebook" gives you the expected result.

So the conclusion is that `keyword` is the culprit here. To solve this we need a tokenizer which will generate seperate tokens as `laptop`, `blue`, `i7`, Easiest way to solve this will be to use `standard` instead of `keyword`.

#### Dealing with multi-word synonym

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55944061/how-to-properly-handle-multi-words-synonym-expansion-using-elasticsearch/55945396#55945396) might help you.